# Login.csthml shows NTAUTHORITY\IUSR instead of ComputerName\WindowsUserName

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've developed a MVC 4 Application in which there is a reference to the `ComputerName\WindowsUserName` user in a login csthml.

When I run the application through the `VS2012` built-in `IIS Express` I succesfully get the desired result. When I publish the same site into `IIS 8.0.9200.16384` (in Windows 8 Build 9200 Version) I get the `NTAUTHORITY\IUSR` user. Why does this happen?

I use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

I have tried all similar  "functions" to get the result but with no result at all.
Any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This means your application pool on the IIS 8 has a different configuration. `IUSR` is the default. You could change it to a specific user to see `COMPUTERNAME\UserName` or `DOMAINNAME\UserName` in the IIS Application Pool properties for Identity.

See [Application Pool Identities](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) for more.

Comment: I've already tested specific user and it worked fine, but the problem is that I want the domain user who logs on into the PC which runs the application. In that way I believe it is not quite helpful to use a specific user because a lot of users log on into this application and not only a specific one.

Comment: Then you need to use `Windows Authentication`, not `Anonymous Authentication`. See [Configure Windows Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: @BrockHensley Thanks